# "Target the specific user you will be using and assign it user id 0/group 0"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, permissions, sudo

I am trying to virtualize an Ubuntu machine using VMWare vCenter Converter, but ran into permissions issues.  I followed the instructions of part 1 and 2 on [this page](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1008164) but when I got to "For Ubuntu operating systems further configuration is needed" I started running into trouble.  I'm decent at Linux, but I'm not an experienced sysadmin.

- How do I `Target the specific user you will be using and assign it
  user id 0/group 0`?
- How do I `Ensure that you also still enable Allow
  root to ssh even though you are not using the root account`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly they're doing, but I think they are suggesting that you make a new account with uid 0 and pretending that it's not a root account (any account with uid 0 is root, no matter what you name it)

Comment: @DerfK can I have 2 root accounts?  That won't mess anything up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I Target the specific user you will be using and assign it user id 0/group 0?

Don't assign the user id or group id 0 to the user you are targeting.  Add the user to `/etc/sudoers` as specified.  Then flag that `sudo` will be uses also as documented.  `sudo` will be used to run command as root (user id 0, group 0) when needed.

> How do I Ensure that you also still enable Allow root to ssh even though you are not using the root account?

This is controlled in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  If keys are used for logins, then you need a line like:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```